# Connect Odata Service with Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, odata

So I am trying to createa sample Odata Service that is connected to a local SQL Server Database. But when I try to call the GET via swagger i get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'string'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'value' in 'string(char[] value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length' in 'string(char[] value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind 'value' in 'string(Char* value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length' in 'string(Char* value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind 'value' in 'string(SByte* value)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length' in 'string(SByte* value, int startIndex, int length)'; cannot bind 'value', 'startIndex', 'length', 'enc' in 'string(SByte* value, int startIndex, int length, Encoding enc)'; cannot bind 'c', 'count' in 'string(char c, int count)'; cannot bind 'value' in 'string(ReadOnlySpan<char> value)'.at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ConstructorBindingFactory.GetBindings(IReadOnlyEntityType entityType, Func`5 bind, InstantiationBinding& constructorBinding, InstantiationBinding& serviceOnlyBinding)
```

Ive used the Visual Studio ASP.NET Core Application Template and ive set up a Microsoft SQLDatabaseServer
Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OData.Models;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
   .Build();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ODataContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));
//builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy());
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
     c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
     c.IgnoreObsoleteActions();
     c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();
     c.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
    var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

OdataContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OData.Models
{
    public class ODataContext : DbContext
    {
        public ODataContext(DbContextOptions<ODataContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().OwnsOne(c => c.Mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Contacts Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Results;
using OData.Models;

namespace OData.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("contactService/contacts")]
    public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<ContactsController> _logger;

        private ODataContext _dbContext;

        public ContactsController(ILogger<ContactsController> logger, ODataContext dbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_dbContext.Contacts);
            return Ok(_dbContext.Contacts);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("key")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public Contact Get([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.SubjectId = key; 
            return contact;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [EnableQuery]
        public void Post(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
        {
            contacts.ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(contacts.ToString());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("confirmMainEmail/key")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public String ConfirmMainEmail([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.SubjectId = key;
            contact.Mail = "example@mail.de";
            return contact.Mail;
        }
    }
}
```

Contact

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace OData.Models
{
    [Table("Contact")]
    public class Contact
    {
        public Contact() { }

        public Contact(int subjectId, String? mail, DateTime created, DateTime updated)
        {
            SubjectId = subjectId;
            Mail = mail;
            Created = created;
            Updated = updated;
        }
    
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        [Column("mail")]
        public String? Mail { get; set; }
        [Column("created")]
        DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [Column("updated")]
        DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The connectionstring ive used is :

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=<PathToMdf>//DatabaseObject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
  }
```

Comment: You didn't show us the code, which causes the failure. Where is string(char[] value)? Where is string(Char* value, int startIndex, int length) ? Debug your code and post the code snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is the thing. As you see in the error there is no file referenced, and that is all the code there is. There is not any more and string() never appears in my code.